# Azure AD auth with WebApplication accessing Resource Server which access another Resource Server

Tags: spring, azure, rest, azure-active-directory

I'm a bit confused about how to build the flow where:

1. I have web application written in Angular which makes http requests to Resource Server (Spring Boot) A.
2. Resource Server A makes http request to Resource Server B (Spring Boot).

So basically there is no direct connection between web application and resource server B. I guess I should configure Resource Server A as a client and as resource server.

I was trying to follow the scenario "Resource server visiting other resource servers" from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-boot-starter-active-directory-readme?view=azure-java-stable
but its kinda confusing for me. For example how should I build the request to Resource Server B with token? What exactly is method "CallGraph" doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> how should I build the request to Resource Server B with token?

use resource-server B's access token to request from resource-server A.

Add the dependencies as mentioned in the document which you have mentioned [above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-boot-starter-active-directory-readme?view=azure-java-stable#resource-server-visiting-other-resource-servers)  in your pom.xml.

Add the properties from the above mentioned link in the application.yml file.

> What exactly is method "CallGraph" doing?

By using @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("graph")  annotation, here callGraph method returning the string "graph" of type "OAuth2AuthorizedClient".

For more info refer this [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/tag_azure-spring-boot_3.6.0/aad/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-resource-server-obo#azure-oauth-20-sample-for-azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-resource-server-obo-client-library-for-java).